# Tensorflow: OneHot-encoding with variable sized length

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, one-hot-encoding

I need to onehot-encode some positions with TensorFlow.

However, the length of the input sequences (and therefore the `depth-argument` in `tf.one_hot`) is None as I work with variable sized inputs.

This throws the following error:

> "ValueError: Tried to convert 'depth' to a tensor and failed. Error: None values not supported.".

Is there a workaround for this?

I have already tried to set the depth to the correct sequence length before each individual call (through a variable that has some arbitrary initialization value) for a given sequence but as the computational graph is already built, the changes do not come into effect and the depth is stuck at the initialization value.

Answer (score 0):

This is how I solved the issue: The problem was that I was using someone else's code and the `depth` argument in `tf.one_hot` was derived from `someTensor.get_shape().as_list()[1]`. The problem here is that if the shape of `someTensor` is unknown, the argument is a Python-`None` which is not a valid argument for `tf.one_hot`. However, using `tf.shape(someTensor)[1]` solved that problem as it returns a Dimension with unknown shape instead of a Python-`None`. A Dimension with unknown shape is a valid `depth`-argument for `tf.one_hot`.